# Generate List of IP Addresses via Command Line?

Tags: perl, command-line, ssh

I'm interested in using command line (possibly Perl) to generate a list of all possible IP addresses.

I've done similar with PHP in the past by using the `long2ip` function and creating a list from 0 to the interger 4294967295.

Is there a way to do this in Perl instead though?

I'm basically just looking for the quickest way to generate a text file that has a list of all 4,294,967,296 possible IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner time?

```
perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -le 'print inet_ntoa(pack "N", $_) for 0..2**32-1'
```

Source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=786521 via quick googling.

Perl isn't strictly necessary either, of course. The following generates a quick `sed` script on the fly and calls it successively.

```
octets () { sed "h;$(for ((i=0; i<256; i++)); do printf "g;s/^/$i./p;"; done)"; }
octets <<<'' | octets | octets  | octets | sed 's/\.$//'
```

The `octets` function generates 256 copies of its input with a (zero-based) line number and a dot prepended to each.  (You could easily append at the end instead, of course.)  In the `sed` scripting language, the `h` command copies the input to the hold space and `g` retrieves it back, overwriting whatever we had there before.  The C-style `for` loop and the `<<<` here string are Bash extensions, so not POSIX shell.

Comment: A one-liner would be great if you can come up with one that works :) This will generate over 255 billion combinations.  There's only 4 billion possible IPs.  The maximum number is 4294967295, corresponding to address 255.255.255.255.  You may want to read up on this:  http://infowaves.eu/tutorials/iptonumber.php

Comment: Huh?  Did you test it?  2**32 is 4 gigs, i.e. exactly the number you are asing for.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use any modules. This is a trivial problem.

```
for my $i (0..255) {
    for my $j (0..255) {
        for my $k (0..255) {
            for my $l (0..255) {
                printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", $i,$j,$k,$l)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will generate over 255 billion combinations.  There's only 4 billion possible IPs.  The maximum number is 4294967295, corresponding to address 255.255.255.255.  You may want to read up on this:  http://infowaves.eu/tutorials/iptonumber.php

Comment: Where do you come up with this number and why are you disparaging solutions apparently without testing them?